# Why does string "\u0022" start with this string "\u204D"

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, string-comparison

Why under .net (Windows 8) does this string comparison return true?

```
"\u0022".StartsWith("\u204D");
```

It is true under all cultures and if you switch the StartsWith to an Equals it returns false.

There are many different characters that return true for a StartsWith comparison. Is this part of an odd Unicode rule or does Windows have its own rules here?

Comment: Look up the name of the right char in a unicode table. Unicode comparisons are subtle. For example certain characters (e.g. zero-width (non)joiner or certain modifiers)are ignored in dome comparisons.

Comment: If you want simple rules,  use ordinal comparisons.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Want to move to Ordinal and I'm running through the possible breaking changes when this one and many others came up.

Comment: Looks to be a normal punctuation character and it only returns true against "\u0022"

Comment: I'd assume it is a bug, you can report it at connect.microsoft.com.  The glyph is conspicuously missing from Windows fonts btw.

Comment: Good question! Reproduced with .NET 4.5 under Windows 7. Can also be written `"\"".StartsWith("⁍")`, of course. If you keep the string `"\""` fixed and let the method argument run over all length-1 strings, you find a lot of similar examples. The first is `"\"".StartsWith("\u00AD")`.

Comment: You: _and if you switch the StartsWith to an Equals it returns false_ That is a bit misleading. The default for `Equals` is to use an ordinal comparison while the default for `StartsWith` is to use the current culture's culture-sensitive comparison. Note that `"\"".Equals("⁍", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)` and `"\u0022".Equals("\u204D", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)` do return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to know what rules lie under the culture-dependent string comparisons. It does seem quite consistent that the punctuations U+0022 `"` (QUOTATION MARK) and U+204D `⁍` (BLACK RIGHTWARDS BULLET) are considered "equal enough" under culture comparisons (including those of the invariant culture). These examples all indicate that:

```
// culture-sensitive:

Console.WriteLine("\"".StartsWith("⁍"));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".StartsWith("\""));
Console.WriteLine("\"".StartsWith("⁍", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

Console.WriteLine("\"".Equals("⁍", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".Equals("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine("\"".Equals("⁍", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".Equals("\"", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Equals("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Equals("⁍", "\""));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals("⁍", "\""));

Console.WriteLine("\"".CompareTo("⁍"));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".CompareTo("\""));

Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare("⁍", "\""));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare("⁍", "\""));
```

Other examples could have been given, for example the `static` methods on `string`, but they are equivalent.

With an *ordinal* comparison, certainly U+0022 must be different from (less than) U+204D (that is simple!):

```
// ordinal:

Console.WriteLine("\"".StartsWith("⁍", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.Ordinal));

Console.WriteLine("\"".Equals("⁍"));
Console.WriteLine("⁍".Equals("\""));

Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals("⁍", "\""));

Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("\"", "⁍"));
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("⁍", "\""));
```